# How can I add text call of functions within a web application?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, canvas, web

I am currently developing a web app and about to get the front end build underway to tie in with the back end.

My plan is in addition to the user clicking icons to add blocks into a WYSIWYG, they can also type a command also. For example if the user wants to add a rectangle to the WYSIWYG canvas the can click the icon rectangle then click the 2 opposite corners on the canvas and hey presto a rectangle appears. In addition, I would like to allow the user to type RECT and then hit ENTER and the rectangle action is then started. The user can then type the Cartesian coords instead of the first and/or second click.

I am not sure of the technology going to be used to create the WYSIWYG canvas, but can anyone advise what would be the best technology to achieve the feature described above? I am not knowledgeable about such matters.

My assumption is that JavaScript could be used to monitor the key strokes and could be used to call the functions, but I am not sure if that would work.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! I am a bit worried I will start paying a contractor to start building in HTML5 then find out that my text input idea is not compatible!

Comment: have you looked into d3? 
http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 2):

It'll be easy man.

Your input might look a little like this: `<input type="text" onchange="check(this)"/>`

You can create little functions to draw shapes. I didn't go into detail, but here is a sample JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gpnb9aba/1/

You can type either Circle or Rect into the box(case sensitive), hit enter, and it will draw it(at a predetermined location). This predetermined location can be assigned a variable and changed with user input, but I didn't do it. My fiddle is just for Proof of Concept.

---

As for drawing rectangles with the mouse, have a look at my other JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lppzrngg/1/

With this jsfiddle, you click and draw to create the two opposite corners of the rectangle, and from there, it will automatically store and draw those rectangles.